# Run backup on HD plugged with systemd

Tags: systemd, backup, backintime

When I plug a HD via USB, it should a) mount it b) run my backup
script.

What I currently have is `backintime.service`

```
[Unit]
Description="Runs backintime to backup."

[Service]
User=user
ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemd-inhibit --what=sleep --why="Backup" "backintime -b"
```

To start the backup script and `backup.mount`

```
[Unit]
Description=Backup Disk
Before=backintime.service

[Mount]
What=/dev/disk/by-uuid/931129c7-7f15-4042-9a69-796c9eb8ffc9
Where=/media/backup
```

But how do I execute it automatically?

Answer (score 4):

I'm struggling to implement a very similar system. I got it to work, but I still want to tweak this and that (see this more general question: [systemd - umount device after service which depends on it finishes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89881/systemd-umount-device-after-service-which-depends-on-it-finishes)).

Here's a working solution to your problem:

**backup.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=<DESCRIPTION HERE>
BindsTo=<STORAGE DEVICE UNIT HERE>.device mnt-backup.mount
After=<STORAGE DEVICE UNIT HERE>.device mnt-backup.mount

[Service]
ExecStart=<CALL TO BACKUP SCRIPT HERE>
```

Note: to get a list of the storage device units use `systemctl list-units --all --full | grep disk`

You might want to add [RefuseManualStart](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#RefuseManualStart=)=yes under [Unit] too.

**mnt-backup.mount**

```
[Unit]
DefaultDependencies=no
Conflicts=umount.target
Before=umount.target

[Mount]
What=/dev/disk/by-uuid/<DEVICE UUID HERE> 
Where=/mnt/backup
Type=<FILESYSTEM HERE>
```

You pretty much got here, now to automaticaly start `backup.service`, we will be using a *udev rule*.

Here also you might want to add RefuseManualStart=yes under [Unit].

**90-backup.rules**

```
KERNEL=="sd*", ATTRS{serial}=="<HD SERIAL HERE>", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="backup.service"
```

Note: to get a list of the attributes of your specific device, include its serial number, use `udevadm info -a -n /dev/sd*`

Comment: To get it work I suppose one runs `sudo systemctl enable` both `service` and `mount` files