# Run systemd service before unmount

Tags: systemd, filesystems, unmounting

I'm trying to run a systemd service at shutdown: it kinda works (it gets called) but it runs after filesystems are unmounted, which is not what I need. So I tried with `Before=umount.target` and `WantedBy=umount.target` without any luck (filesystems are unmounted before running the service). When I say "filesystems" I mean all but the root.

Is there any other target to pay attention to?

Comment: Is it too nasty to mount it again in the service, run your intended function in the service and unmount it back again?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89881/systemd-umount-device-after-service-which-depends-on-it-finishesmight give some ideas

Comment: Of course I'll do as you suggest, but I can't believe it doesn't exist a proper way to make it work LOL

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `DefaultDependencies=no` to the Unit section of the service file.
*systemd.service* manpage says:

> The following dependencies are added unless DefaultDependencies=no is set:
>
> ```
>   •   Service units will have dependencies of type Requires= and After= on sysinit.target, a dependency of type After= on basic.target as well
>       as dependencies of type Conflicts= and Before= on shutdown.target. These ensure that normal service units pull in basic system
>       initialization, and are terminated cleanly prior to system shutdown. Only services involved with early boot or late system shutdown
>       should disable this option.
> ```
>
> ...

Comment: Can you explain why this might help? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.